# I have to create two way table from a data given to me it has the cities and number of accidents,number of deaths in the year 2018

Tags: probability, statistics

Create a two ways probability table for the selected part of the
data you are focusing at

• Five different conditional probability calculations and a
description of how they might be used to make predictions about
the group analyzed or to understand the data.

I have to create two way table from a data given to me it has the cities and number of accidents,number of deaths in the year 2018 i have all data for it

I have been given the emirates abu dhabi, dubai along with number of accidents and number of deaths that occurred during the year 2018 but idk how to make 2 way table for that

Normally we make two way table for that data like we have number of males and females but in this question i have these things so can i make two way table

I have number of fine,traffic deaths,number of injuries,number of traffic accidents. I don't have any data for fatal or non fatal accidents

Comment: i have been given the emirates abu dhabi,dubai along with number of accidents and number of deaths tht occured during the year 2018 but idk how to make 2 way table for that

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: normally we make two way table for that data like we have number of males and females but in this question i have these things so can i make two way table

Comment: Your first comment should be part of your question body.

Comment: You could make a distinction between fatal and non fatal accidents. But you shouldn't just copy/paste the assignment...

Comment: i have number of fine,traffic deaths,number of injuries,number of traffic accidents,

Comment: i dont have any data for fatal or non fatal accidents

Comment: can i make my own data like accidents,fines caused by male and female.But i have given a one way data so can i do that plzz answer